# Refresh Table After Form Submit PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm unsure how much code is needed to illustrate my problem.  If you need more, please ask!

I have a table that's created with a php function.  It pulls all of a user's records based on their ID.

I also have a form that calls a javascript function when submitted.  This function contains validation, then creates a XMLHttpRequest that submits the form values to insert_into.php and then changes the .innerHTML of a span to show a success message.

Everything so far works great!

Now the annoying bit:  I want to refresh the .innerHTML of "myTable" with the new info that was just submitted to the database.  I can get my code to output a second table with the new info, but I've been wholly unsuccessful in getting it to update the .innerHTML and I'm going crazy.

This is the part that I *think* is causing the issue:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

//create the function to be executed when the server response is ready
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("form_message_hybrid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        
            //second XMLHttpRequest object, to update table
            var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
            //handle second server response
            xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (xhttp2.status === 200) {
                        var updatedTable = xhttp2.responseText;
                
                        document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }//if xhttp2 readstate close
                    else {
                        alert("Error updating myTable. Status: " + xhttp2.status);
                    }
                }
            };//xhttp2 function close
        
            xhttp2.open("GET", "query.php?action=hybridsTable", true);
            xhttp2.send();
        }//first if statement close
        else {
            alert("Error inserting record.  Status: " + xhttp.status);
        }
    }
};//xhttp.onreadystatechange close

//prepare send to insert_into.php file with the entered variables
xhttp.open("GET", "insert_into.php?parent_one=" + parent_one + "&parent_two=" + parent_two + "&hybrid_name=" + hybrid_name + "&animal_name=" + animal_name + "&animal_location=" + animal_location, true);

//send the variables to the php file, form will either reset and display a
//sucess message, or fail verification
xhttp.send();
```

php:

```
function hybridsTable() {
    $conn = conn();
    global $userID;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hybrids WHERE fk_hybrids_users = " . $userID;
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
    $output = "<table class='table' id='myTable'><tr><th>Parent One</th><th>Parent Two</th><th>Species</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th>";
    
    
    if ($results && $results->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $output .= "<tr>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_parent_one'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_parent_two'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_hybrid_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_animal_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_animal_location'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . "</td>";
            $output .= "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        $output .= "<tr><td colspan='4'>No results found.</td></tr>";
    }

   $output .= "</table>";

    echo $output;
}
```

Things that I can eliminate:

1. Database connection issues.  All my code uses the same connection, everything else works fine, and even if it didn't I can consistently produce the table, just not in the right place!
2. Some other issue with making the table itself, see above.
3. The table id is definitely myTable, both the one that's supposed to be there and the second one that variations of the code have produced.
4. Placing the xhttp2 section outside of the xhttp if statement doesn't seem to help.
5. I've tried both echo and return for the $output variable in the php code.

Edit - I tried the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="tableWrapper">
   <?php initTable(); ?> 
</div>
```

js:

```
xhttpRequest ("GET", "query.php?action=hybridsTable", "tableWrapper");
```

I created a function to handle the xhttp requests and this is sending the method, the action, and the id of the element to be changed to that function.

```
function xhttpRequest (method, page, elemID) {

    var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //handle second server response
    xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhttp2.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById(elemID).innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }//if xhttp2 readstate close
            else {
                alert("Error updating myTable. Status: " + xhttp2.status);
            }
        }
    };//xhttp2 function close
        
    xhttp2.open(method, page, true);
    xhttp2.send();

}
```

PHP:

```
function hybridsTable() {
    $conn = conn();
    global $userID;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hybrids WHERE fk_hybrids_users = " . $userID;
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
    $output = "";   
    
    if ($results && $results->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $output .= "<tr>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_parent_one'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_parent_two'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_hybrid_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_animal_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_animal_location'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . "</td>";
            $output .= "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        $output .= "<tr><td colspan='4'>No results found.</td></tr>";
    }

   //$output .= "</table>";
    
    return $output;
}
```

setting $output = ""; rather than  results in:

```
<span id="form_message_hybrid">Record inserted sucessfully.CowParrotCorretAdele29...the rest of the data</span>
```

Comment: Are you calling your `hybridsTable` function *in the PHP file*? Seems like you're missing a `hybridsTable();` call right there.

Comment: This is some very peculiar looking code - sending the request to `insert_into.php` before issuing another request to fetch table data. Can you show how / when you call the PHP function shown above and also how the ajax is triggered? `I also have a form that calls a javascript function when submitted` - where is the form? Which javascript function?

Comment: @Alexis88 Yes, the hybridsTable function is in the query.php file.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Do you have a good way for me to show a ton of code, both PHP and javascript?  I don't think jsfiddle accepts PHP. There is quite a bit, and I didn't want to overwhelm anyone!

Comment: @Kendra Your link is broken. :/

Comment: Sorry about that!  It was set to private.  https://github.com/cemtai2/Let-s-Build-a-Zoo-Utility

Comment: @Kendra What happens if you place the whole `hybridsTable` function code outside and print the `$output` instead of return it? Is there a `hybridsTable()` call outside the function's body? It would be great if you update your repository and tell us the names of critical files.

Comment: @Alexis88 I've been offline for a few days, back now.  The names of the critical files are app.php, insert_into.php, query.php, hybridsTabContent.php from the tabIncludes folder, and query.js and submit_form.js from the js folder. I have tried echo instead of return and it didn't help.  There is a hybridsTable() call outside the function's body, and it does work as it prints the correct output, just in the wrong place.

Comment: @Kendra Did you update your repo with the latest changes you made?

Answer (score 0):

Okay not seeing the whole situation I might be misunderstanding, and this might be silly, so sorry about that.
But, in this line of code:

```js
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

shouldn't you have

```js
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = xhttp2.responseText;
```

or, more easily

```js
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = updatedTable;
```

Comment: I set it equal to "test" at one point - it still appears in the same place.  A new table with "myTable" as the ID created inside the success message <span> tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing to call the `hybridsTable` function inside the PHP file and that's why you have not get a response.

Putting some order in your requests code, this way it should work. You must call the first function, which in this example is named as `sendForm`, in a certain moment; eg. clicking a button, sending a form, etc.

```js
function sendForm(){
    const 
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = "insert_into.php?parent_one=" + parent_one + "&parent_two=" + parent_two + "&hybrid_name=" + hybrid_name + "&animal_name=" + animal_name + "&animal_location=" + animal_location;

    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.addEventListener("load", function(){
        if (this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("form_message_hybrid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            fillTable(); //Call the second function
        }
        else{
            alert("Error inserting record.  Status: " + xhttp.status);
        }
    });
}

function fillTable(){
    const 
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = "query.php";

    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.addEventListener("load", function(){
        if (this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        else{
            alert("Error filling table.  Status: " + xhttp.status);
        }
    });
}

//Calling the function at some point...
sendForm();
```

And then you call your `hybridsTable` function in your PHP file...

```
function hybridsTable(){
    $conn = conn();
    global $userID;
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hybrids WHERE fk_hybrids_users = " . $userID;
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
    
    //Don't create a new table, but a new row
    $output = "<tr><th>Parent One</th><th>Parent Two</th><th>Species</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th>";    
    
    if ($results && $results->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $output .= "<tr>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_parent_one'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_parent_two'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_hybrid_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_animal_name'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . $row['hybrids_animal_location'] . "</td>";
            $output .= "<td>" . "</td>";
            $output .= "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        $output .= "<tr><td colspan='4'>No results found.</td></tr>";
    }

    echo $output;
}

//Calling the function...
hybridsTable();
```

Or just put the `hybridsTable` function code outside the function block in order to execute its instructions at the moment when you send the request.

Try and let us know how it went.

Comment: Wouldn't the updated table not show at all if the hybridsTable function wasn't called?  I did try it, just in case, and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Kendra Then it could be a repeated element problem. You are filling a `<table id="myTable">` content with another `<table id="myTable">`. That's why I deleted the `<table id="myTable">` tag in my example. Just update table's `tbody` or the wrapper element where that table is placed.

Comment: I deleted the extra <table> tag, but all that does is dump it as plain text into the <span>.  I tried removing it and updating the wrapper, but it didn't help. It leaves tableWrapper empty and updates the <span>

Comment: @Kendra If that wrapper is **not** a `<table>`, then it's safe to set the request's response as its content. The problem is that you show this `$output = "<table class='table' id='myTable'><tr>...` but also this `document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = this.responseText`. Basically you put a table with `myTable` as its ID into another table with `myTable` as its ID. That's what it makes nonsense. Which is the wrapper's ID?

Comment: html: `<div class="row" id="tableWrapper">
  <?php initTable(); ?>
</div>`

js: `xhttpRequest ("GET", "query.php?action=hybridsTable", "tableWrapper");` I created a function to handle the xhttp requests and this is sending the method, the action, and the id of the element to be changed to that function.

PHP: setting $output = ""; rather than <table >

This results in: `<span id="form_message_hybrid">Record inserted sucessfully.CowParrotCorretAdele29...the rest of the data</span>`

Comment: @Kendra Can you please update your original question with only the *critical* block code you just added? It's a bit difficult to read all those code lines in a comment section. :/

Comment: I've added an edit with the updated code.  I also have a link to my github repository up, if that helps!